# Trying to get Worker into React - __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lamejs___default is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got so close with this.

I'm doing something similar to [this example](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/blob/master/src/js/plugins/lamejs-plugin.js) where [lamejs](https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs) is run in a web worker.

I'm using react scripts and found a work around for getting the web worker in via a blob.

My problem is that webpack can't find the library and I get the error

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lamejs___default is not defined\
```

When I try and use it as such

```
import lamejs from 'lamejs'

mp3Encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, config.sampleRate || 44100, config.bitRate || 123)
```

How can I get Webpack to properly insert lamejs into a webworker passed in as a blob?

Comment: Did you try using a webpack loader for your module: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader. I used that in my project and it's super easy. Also this one looks interesting: https://github.com/developit/workerize